# Languages that compile to Java Bytecode and can run on the JVM

Tags: java, jvm, embedded

I am an embedded programmer and working with an embedded JVM.

This enables running Java files on constrained devices.
These Java files are first compiled to bytecode into .class files which are then further optimized and uploaded to the device which has a micro JVM to run the optimized bytecode.
The micro JVM does not support all features, e.g., no reflection.

The main benefit is obvious: this allows programming in Java for constrained devices.
However, I was thinking that plenty of languages compile to bytecode, some are listed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode.
So in theory these languages could also be used to program.

I'd like to obtain a list of common languages that compile down to bytecode and was wondering if you could help.
For example, Python has special implementations that reduce to Java Bytecode, if I'm not mistaken, and stuff like C to Java virtual machine compilers also exist.

So what languages would you think are logical to try and run on the devices? Any pointers on how to or similar experiences?
Also, I'm not clear what the difference is from reading Wikipedia between (Python) bytecode and Java bytecode, could anybody help explain that?

Comment: I would be very surprised if cross language compilers were not making creative use of the JVM to support features the JVM wasn't designed for. i.e. most likely they all use a feature your micro JVM doesn't support.  I suggest you start with the common ones, and I would use google to see how these are trending or how many hits they get.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions which seek a list do not meet the Stackoverflow requirement for specific answerability.

Comment: FreePascal has JVM backend: http://wiki.freepascal.org/FPC_JVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm agree with you about the overall idea and it would be nice to develop an embedded application using any language that can run on a JVM. But there are some practical issues that you should consider and I think that's why none of major vendors or open source initiatives have any active/serious project on this (as far as I know).

As you mentioned, a JVM implementations that can run on embedded devices, each have their own constraints and limitations. The most obvious one is that some packages may not be available at runtime. In order to apply such a constraint, you should either control it in the compile process or have a toolchain (sort of an SDK) which accepts the bytecode and checks such constraints.

This situation would be worth when a developer tries to use a third party library that is available for that specific language. It's not easy to guess if a library is safe for use against such a framework or not.

One great facility for developers would be to have their IDE check such issues on the fly (something like inspection in IntelliJ Idea). This makes it much more smoother to move toward using such a solution. But again the problem is that for each such languages there need to be a specific plugin compatible with their own syntax.

Also some of JVM languages that are actually implementation of an existing language (e.g. Jython or JRuby) are most of the time out of sync with the original language in case of supporting libraries/syntax changes of that language.

Anyway, I think in order to have a list of JVM languages you could easily find them on Wikipedia. Maybe you mean those who may worth considering in this regard by having a large community and tools support. In my opinion, you should focus on the following JVM languages as those who may worth to include in your final list:

- Groovy
- Kotlin
- Scala

These are all pure JVM languages and are only using different syntax than Java.

Regarding the topic in general, I should say that when you search for embedded JVM implementations, you'll notice that it's also a fairly academic concepts and they're so many publications in this topics regarding the overall architecture, threading support, toolchain, error handling, memory management, etc. This means that you should have a very great experiences/background on both embedded systems and programming language concepts and implementation to be able to devise a proper architecture for such a platform.

About your last question regarding the difference between Python bytecode and Java bytecode (if I understand your question correctly), these are both conceptually the same but each has its own syntax and constraints. The bytecode concept refers to the piece of software that is the output of the compiler and is the platform independent representation of the original code and can be run/interpreted at runtime by another software component which is the virtual machine. In Java world, this software is called the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). I'm from the Java world so I don't know what it's called in Python vocabulary but it should be something similar (e.g. Python virtual machine).

I think due to the complexity of developing such a toolchain and also considering the unprecedented development of new IoT and SoC devices, many of them capable of running a more higher level operating systems, maybe in a long run most developers prefer to develop for a more high end devices using more high level APIs and SDKs. Who knows! In that case,  we would have a same situation that we're in today for PCs. Languages like C and Assembly are still in use, but they have their own domain of applications. I mean throughout the time, layers of abstraction are being added on top of the previous one. The same thing can happen for embedded devices.